# Why the output of this c program gives diffrent result whenever i change the position of variable initialization?

Tags: arrays, c

Look at this program, when I initialize the `count` variable at beginning of program it gives incorrect result but gives correct when it declared inside first loop.(as it is shown), why is this happening?

This source code is basically for count the frequency of elements in an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[100], freq[100];
    int size, i, j, count;
    
    /* Input size of array */
    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    /* Input elements in array */
    printf("Enter elements in array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        /* Initially initialize frequencies to -1 */
        freq[i] = -1;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        count = 1;
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            /* If duplicate element is found */
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                count++;
                /* Make sure not to count frequency of same element again */
                freq[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    
        /* If frequency of current element is not counted */
        if (freq[i] != 0) {
            freq[i] = count;
        }
    }
    
    /* Print frequency of each element */
    printf("\nFrequency of all elements of array : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (freq[i] != 0) {
            printf("%d occurs %d times\n", arr[i], freq[i]);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

case1: when i initialize count's value at beginning as,

```
  #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
 int arr[100], freq[100];
 int size, i, j, count;
 count=1; //***LOOK HERE I INITIALIZE ITS VALUE***

 /* Input size of array */
```

.
.
[IN CASE 1 WE GOT INCORRECT OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejVWu.png)

case2: when i initialize count's value inside first for loop as,

```
   .
   .   
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    count = 1; //***HERE I INITIALIZE ITS VALUE INSIDE FIRST FOR LOOP***

    for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
        /* If duplicate element is found */
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {

 .
 .
```

[IN CASE 2 WE GOT CORRECT OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxsDc.png)

Comment: Please show the version that doesn't work. Also, please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: I don't see a `count` variable declared inside a loop?

Comment: `for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)` , what if  `i == size -1`  ?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    count = 1; //Here that "count" variable is initialized but when i initialize it at beginning of program after its declaration its gives incorrect result.
    for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
    {

Comment: *when i initialize it at beginning of program*. But that's not logically the same as setting it in the loop. The intialisation only happens **once** whereas setting in the loop resets it to 1 for **every iteration** of the loop.

Comment: @Dev: Can you show a version of the code that doesn't work as a single example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*> when I initialize the count variable at beginning of program it gives incorrect result...*

because for every element in the array you need to reset the `count` to `1` otherwise the `count` will have previous element count value (number of occurrence of previous element in array) and the current element count will start from that value which will result in wrong count value for the current element.

*> but gives correct when it declared inside first loop.(as it is shown),*

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    count = 1;
```

this is not declaration, this is **assignment** (assigning `1` to `count`). Here, for every element before counting it's occurrence in array, `count` is reset to `1` and the nested `for` loop increments the `count` for every occurrence of that element further in the array. Hence you are getting correct result.

Since, the `count` is only used inside the outer `for` loop, you can declare it in the outer `for` loop body to avoid any confusion, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int count = 1;   // initialising the count with value 1
```

You should do one optimization in your code - don't process the repeated elements again. Check the `freq` of that element and if it is not `-1` (i.e. already processed) then don't process it:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (j = i + 1; (j < size) && (freq[i] == -1); j++)  // added freq[i] check
    {
        /* If duplicate element is found */
        if (arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            count++;

            /* Make sure not to count frequency of same element again */
            freq[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    /* If frequency of current element is not counted */
    if (freq[i] == -1)
    {
        freq[i] = count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you should count each value separately. If you initialize outside the for loop you would be accumulating the sum of different values.

Suppose you have the array:  `{1, 3, 5, 6, 1, 8, 9, 1, 3, 2, 1}`.

You start the loop counting the `1's` and you have `4` in your variable after the first round of the loop.

Then in the second round you are about to count the frequency of `3's`and you are starting with the `counter` set to `4`, not `0` like it should be.